# Amazon Cloud Front for EC2 instance returns 403 Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have a running EC2 instance on AWS. I wanted to track the visitors on certain pages and thought Cloud Front will be good for that. I created a Cloud Front distribution with origin domain name as ec2-xx-xx-xx-xxx.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com.
Upon creation of cloud front distribution I got domain dxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net. I tried and it works on home page and other static pages. But when I try to log in to my web portal it does give me "Access Denied" 403. Any specific configurations I should look at? Will cloud front work with website that has to connect to a database ? My database is hosted on amazon RDS.

Thanks,

Comment: The most likely explanation is that you did not configure the cache behavior for the web portal to forward the necessary headers and/or cookies that your application needs to see.  Check this?

Comment: Hi, I have headers Get Post delete and options selected so theoretically it should allow me to post data. Also i made sure inbound rules for the security group of EC2 has port 80 and 443 open.

Comment: Please capture the response headers and body of a failed request and edit them into your question.